# Not able to showing error messages from dynamic action(pl/sql)

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle12c

I am using `oracle 12c Database` and `oracle apex 5`.

I have developed sample application for generating interactive report on button clicked.

I have created dynamic action with Pl/sql code.

This dynamic action execute after button click.

Dynamic action execute perfectly with generating interactive report including raise_application_error(if occurred).

But my question is raise_application_error is not showing user friendly messages Instead of that is any other way to displaying error message properly from dynamic action(with pl/sql code)

I am also tried apex_application.g_print_success_message := 'my error';

but this is not working.

So please some body help me to solving this issu.

Comment: May be you should try Process with When button pressed condition instead of Dynamic Action. Process have Process Error Message property.

Comment: Please can you tell me how to write process with When button pressed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Alone Go to tab "Processing", create new process, in process's properties go to Condition block, and there When button pressed.

[image]

Comment: Thanks that Working for me!